# Mask sensitive data in maven mojo parameter

Tags: maven, logging, slf4j, maven-mojo

I have a Maven Mojo where you have to pass user credentials. Now when you run the plugin with debug output these credentials are output on the StdOut.

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT:plugin' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) name = muster
[DEBUG]   (f) password = should-be-secret
[DEBUG]   (f) other = other
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Is there a way to mask single variables like `password`?

I have already tried the Maven documentation but unfortunately the configuration is not taken into account. Below src/main/resources I have already placed both the `simplelogger.properties` and various `Logback.xml` files. None of them worked.

The idea would be, as suggested here on Stackoverflow, to create an appropriate Masking PatternLayout and then apply it via configuration.

Comment: My assumption is that you have a filed which is called `password` in your Mojo correct?

Comment: Yes, as it says in the question I have a field password.